# The geometry of the holomorph of a Lie group

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras

Every Lie group  $G$ is naturally  contained  in its  holomorph Hol($G$) = $G \rtimes $ Aut($G$)

> Is Hol$(G)$ always a Lie group?

If the answer is yes our main questions:

> 1.For a left invariant metric $g$ of Hol($G$), are there always two left invariant metrics $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ of $G$ and Aut($G$), respectively such that $g$ is conformal to the product of $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$? (motivated by $G=\mathbb{R}$, as an example of this situation)
>
> 2. For what type of  Lie  groups, $G$ is  a totally geodesic submanifold of its  holomorph? As we see,  $G=\mathbb{R}$ does not satisfies this property, but to what extent those Lie groups with this propery are studied?
>
> 3.Motivated by Poincare upper halph plane $\mathbb{H}^{2}\simeq \mathbb{R} \rtimes \mathbb{R}^{+}$, is it true to say that Aut($G$) is always a totally geodesic submanifold of Hol($G$)?

And finally: can one write the lie  algebra of Hol($G$) in term of Lie algebras of $G$ and $Aut(G)$ and also the natural action of $Aut(G)$ on the Lie algebra of $G$?

Comment: $Hol(G)$ is always a Lie group, since $G$ and $Aut(G)$ are Lie groups and the action is smooth. The Lie algebra is $\mathfrak{g}\rtimes Der(\mathfrak{g})$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  thank you very much for your comment. Could you please give a reference for your last part of your comment. Is it easy to proof?

Comment: A reference is [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=CA4aBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA317&lpg=PA317&dq=The+Lie+algebra+of+the+semidirect+product+of+Lie+group+G+x+Aut%28G%29&source=bl&ots=oJt5crWoXC&sig=Ff-i5p6rLKxHLLLNli1KZdVBUXc&hl=de&sa=X&ei=yiS-VN3lHYXwaKHEgsAD&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=The%20Lie%20algebra%20of%20the%20semidirect%20product%20of%20Lie%20group%20G%20x%20Aut%28G%29&f=false); $G$ should be connected and simply connected to conclude that $Aut(\mathfrak{g})\simeq Aut(G)$.

Comment: Some assumptions are also needed to ensure that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is a Lie group ($G$ virtually connected is enough), see the comments in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589303/lie-algebra-of-the-automorphism-group-of-a-lie-group